# Redirect only when url has a certain word using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Example :

`www.example.com/city-ab-cd+xy+zy`

`www.example.com/state-abc-cdx+xyx+zyx`

**Url contain only city or state then work below redirection rules.**

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)-([+a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([+a-zA-Z0-9]*)\.html$ /xyz.php?$1=$2 [L]
```

Otherwise above redirection rules are skip is it possible?

Comment: where do you want to redirect?

Comment: Right now above redirection rule applied on most of url which contain similar url i.e. example.com/abc-xyz-hello.phtml,  is also redirect on xyz.php. RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)-([+a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([+a-zA-Z0-9]*)\.html$ /xyz.php?$1=$2 [L]

Comment: I am asking where does it redirect?

Comment: let me explain : I need to redirect on xyz.php only when url contain state / cite otherwise url go for our location not in xyz.php. hope you got my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below rules I am assuming you are only redirecting not passing any thing to `xyz.php`,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (city|state)
RewriteRule ^ /xyz.php [R=301]
```

Comment: You rock #Abhishek

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below code for redirection

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^city-([^/]+)/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^state-([^/]+)/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Thanks 
Ridev